# why the exception severity is always set to 16 for throw

Tags: sql-server

When I am using try catch block instead of RAISERROR I used THROW. For every error the severity level is generated with 16. Even in msdn also it is like the severity is 16 for throw. Is there any particular reason for getting 16?

Answer (score 0):

Severity 16 has always been the default severity for errors.  And there's very little utility in examining the Severity, except that Severity <= 10 is an informational message.

See

```
select  severity, count(*) 
from sys.messages
where language_id = 1033
group by severity
order by severity
```

Returns

```
severity 
-------- -----------
0        104
10       2338
11       85
12       1
13       2
14       82
15       510
16       9662
17       148
18       12
19       5
20       134
21       82
22       17
23       21
24       10

(16 rows affected)
```